# Object prototype interference with Easeljs

Tags: javascript, prototype, easeljs

I was setting up a little helper function like so:

```
if (!Object.prototype.__construct) {
Object.prototype.__construct = function() {
    if (typeof arguments[0] !== 'object' ||
        arguments.length === 0) return;
    for (var name in arguments[0]) {
        if (arguments[0].hasOwnProperty(name))
            this[name] = arguments[0][name];
    }
}}

if (!Object.prototype.__)
    Object.prototype.__ = Object.prototype.__construct;
```

It is invoked like such:

```
function Foo(props) {
    this.__(props); // or this.__construct(props);
    ...
}
var foo = new Foo({a:1,b:2,c:3});
```

As you can see, it just acts as a simple constructor. However when using it with EaselJS, specifically `SpriteSheet()` I get an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined`. Here is a snippet of code illustrating where the issue arises:

```
var ss = new SpriteSheet({
    images: ...,
    frames: {
        ...
    },
    animations: {
        walk: [0, 1, "walk", 8] // <-- Error caused here.
    }
});
```

So, is there a better way to go about writing an Object prototype like this, which will not cause a (presumably) clash with Easel? Or possibly a better way altogether? (Native?). Thanks.

Comment: Extending the `Object` prototype is a bad idea.

Comment: @zzzzBov Could you please elaborate or link me to some reference?

Comment: After a very brief amount of searching, I've found [this article which explains some of the pros and cons](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/extending-javascript-natives/), "Extending Object.prototype 'is Verboten'

For some or all of these reasons, the JavaScript community has considered Object.prototype extensions taboo for several years..."

Comment: Basically, if you start overriding `Object.prototype` you can expect libraries (such as jQuery) to start failing, and devs that view your code to start hating you.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Same reasons I would imagine. However the convenience this brings for my small project is really nice. Any ideas on how resolve besides not doing it, ha?

Comment: Your function is not a constructor function, it simply extends an object with another object's properties. jQuery has this as [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), Underscore has this as [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend), so I would follow their lead and leave it as a static function that merges properties into the first object parameter provided.